# Editing working PS Code to include TREE Command

Tags: powershell

The code below outputs the contents of **Folder1** to a CSV file and saves it to C:. It works perfectly fine. The limitation of this code is that it only outputs the content of one folder, in this case, the **Folder1** folder.

I would like to edit the code so it uses the TREE function within a loop and if there are multiple folders under the **Folder1** folder, it will drill down each folder and capture all of the folder names and write it to the CSV as well.

I hope I'm explaining what I'm looking for. I understand how this code works enough to get the outputs I need but as I didn't originally write this code and have limited coding experience any help would be appreciated.

```
$Directory = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder1"
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
 
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -LiteralPath $Directory -File | 
ForEach {
        
    $File = $_.Name
    $Directory = $_.Directory
    

    
    
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Directory = $Directory
        Name = $File
        Size = "$([int]($_.length / 1kb)) KB"
        LastWrite = $_.LastWriteTime
        CreationTime = $_.CreationTime
        
    }
    
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Test.CSV" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ","
```

Comment: This already does what you are looking for https://github.com/santisq/PSTree

Comment: When I run your code on a path, it already recurses through all child folders - are you able to share your folder structure that you're testing with as well as the output you're getting on that test?

Comment: @AnthonyNorwood So if I run this on Folder1 and it has 2 subfolders call them Folder2 and Folder3 it will only work on the top folder, so it will Run through Folder1 one then run through Folder2 but skip folder3. What i would like it to do is run through Folder2 then go back and see if there is another folder at that level and if there is run through it and then repeat, if no more folders exist at that level I'd like it to go back to the Folder1 level and if there is more folders at that Folder1 level then repeat if not then just end.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon how do I use that?

Comment: `Get-PSTree $Directory -Recurse -Force | Select-Object Hierarchy, Size, LastWriteTime, CreationTime | Export-Csv...`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thats all of the code? how does that work with my existing code?

Comment: the module is a tree command for powershell, so it has nothing to do with your code, the cmdlet does all you want by itself. perhaps open the link and read.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon This works for graphically displaying what I need but I don't see a way for it to output to a CSV file